# How to construct not-joke in french?

Tags: anglais, constructions, humour

How would you construct a so called not-joke in french, where you say the "not" in the end to create irony.

E.g.: The sky is red, not!

Comment: I've never understood the grammar in no-jokes, is a sentence like that even correct: "The sky is red not"? Whatever, I think what you are looking for is adding "... ou pas". "Tu es vraiment adorable... ou pas".

Comment: True. I would punctuate it thus: "The sky is red... Not!" This reflects the pause (which can be of highly variable length!) better and we only have to call "Not" an interjection negating whatever went before rather than integrate it into an otherwise correct sentence. :) Also, minor nuance note: in that context I'd suggest "Anyway" or "In any case" instead of "Whatever" (which as an interjection carries something of the sense of "Je m'en fiche")

Comment: Incidentally, in my experience this structure is mostly used by children born in the '90s, primarily for insults (the first thing is a compliment, followed by "Not!"). I'm not sure it's a "joke" so much as that the humour comes from the surprise, but I see that it does have that moniker anyway... but (a) I'm not sure "The sky is red" is likely to occur in one, and (b) any answers should take into account that register!

Comment: First of all, this is not a joke. It is merely youth "dialect" AmE. It is also quite recent (last ten years??). And as such, I don't see a structural way of translating it. A suggestion: Le ciel est rouge, c'est  ça. If  used with the right tone, it actually means the sky is not red at all.

Comment: @Lambie This comment is an excellent answer; what keeps you from making a full fledged answer of ti?

Comment: @LPH Thank you for the compliment. When I have given what I deem to have been some pretty good answers, I get nitpicked to death (or did at one point), told I am misbehaving and am thus just too tired to argue with all the commentary. :)

Comment: @Lambie "Hounded to death" did you say recently, if I remember right; don't let it get to you! Let the world say what it will!

Comment: @LPH Yes, indeed, I did say that. :) I was also sent a tsk-tsk email from the mods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest "ou pas" :

"Le ciel est rouge, ou pas !"

Answer (score 8):

***Ou pas*** is idiomatic but leaves some uncertainty not present in the English "**Not!**"

An alternative expression can be ***[Eh bien](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Eh%20bien) non !*** often simplified in spoken French to ***Eh ben non !*** or ***Et ben non !***

> Le ciel est rouge… eh ben non !

Comment: Je ne perçois pas le côté comique de tout ceci (autant en anglais qu'en français), mais ça me semble en effet plus près de l'original. En souhaitant qu'aucune vague de not-jokes ne déferle en Francophonie...

Comment: @Feelew Commentaire très pertinent.

... Eh ben non !!

(Kidding, of course.)

Comment: So, are these meant to poke fun at people? C'est délicieusement amusant... Eh ben non! (Half-kidding, of course).

Comment: @Feelew I will report your sarcastic comments to a mod! *Eh ben non !* ;-)