# Jokingly saying “Or am I?” or “Or did I?” and stuff like that?

Tags: expressions, langage-informel, humour

Is there anything in French like the sarcastic “Or x?”

*“Well, I bought you this really cool toy... or did I?”*

*“I’m not really going away... or am I?”*

*”Grandma said you could have an extra cookie... or did she?”*

It’s kind of like a way to mock someone jokingly or to tease them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a case where ***[ou pas](https://blog.francetvinfo.fr/les-mots/2014/08/07/ou-pas-une-expression-sympa-ou-pas.html)*** will perfectly fit, better than as a translation of "not jokes" for which it was accepted in [an earlier question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25437/how-to-construct-not-joke-in-french).

> *Je t'ai apporté ce ce super jouet... **ou pas**...*
>
> *Je reste là... **ou pas**...*
>
> *Je ne vais pas vraiment partir... **ou peut-être que si**...* (Here ***ou pas*** can't work because the main part is already negative.)
>
> *Mamie a dit que tu pouvais prendre un autre gâteau... **ou pas**...*